# Node is returning as null

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, nodes

I'm testing to make sure I can print out my Binary Search Tree for a project in my class. I have it so that a string expression is established, and from there, the program will split the string into an array, and will insert each element into a root Node. I've debugged the program, and it seems to insert the Nodes correctly, but at the end, when the program stops looping, the root Node will end up being null, and won't allow me to print the binary tree.

Why is my root Node returning null? I tried looking through the program, but I can't find the error

Node class

```
public class Node<T>
{
private T value;
Node left;
Node right;

public Node(T value)
{
    this.value=value;
    left=null;
    right=null;

}

public String toString()
{
    return value.toString();
}

public T getValue()
{

    return value;
}

public Node getLeft() {
    return left;
}

public void setLeft(Node left) {
    this.left = left;
}

public Node getRight() {
    return right;
}

public void setRight(Node right) {
    this.right = right;
}

public void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}



}
```

Binary Search Tree class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class binarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>>
{

private Node<T> root;




public binarySearchTree()
{
    root=null;
}







public Node<T> buildTree(String expression)
{

    String[] expressionSplit=expression.split("\\s{1,}");
    binarySearchTree<String> stringBST=new binarySearchTree<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<expressionSplit.length;i++)
    {
        stringBST.insert(expressionSplit[i]);
    }

    return root;
}














public Node<T> insertHelper(Node<T> p, T data)
{
    if(p==null)
    {

        return new Node<T>(data);
    }

    int test=data.compareTo(p.getValue());
    if(test==0)
    {
        return p;
    }
    if(test<0)
    {
        p.left=insertHelper(p.left,data);
    }
    else if(test>0)
    {
        p.right=insertHelper(p.right,data);
    }

    return p;
}
public void insert(T data)
{
    root=insertHelper(root,data);
}
public static String inorder(Node<String> rootString)
{
    if(rootString!=null)
    {
        return inorder(rootString.getLeft())+rootString.getValue()+" "+inorder(rootString.getRight());
    }
    return "";
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String expression="10 8 17 4";
    binarySearchTree<String>test=new binarySearchTree<String>();
    Node<String> root=test.buildTree(expression);
    System.out.println(test.inorder(root));
}
}
```

Comment: You keep shadowing the `root` variable. Every time you write `Node<String> root`, that's a new variable that will not modify or update your instance variable `private Node<T> root;`

Comment: You have a member `root` and a bunch of local variables and parameters also called `root`. Makes it hard to keep track of which `root` you're playing with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically returning the `root` object that you declared in `buildTree` method which is always null.

To fix this remove `Node<T> root = null;` from that method.

Also, you are creating a new `BinarySearchTree` object which in your `buildTree` method. So, the `root` object that gets updated is the one in that object.

The original `root` object from the `BinarySearchTree` in your `main` method never gets updated and it's always null.

Change your `buildTree` method to look like this.

```
public Node<T> buildTree(String expression)
{
    T[] expressionSplit = (T[]) expression.split("\\s{1,}");
    for (int i = 0; i < expressionSplit.length; i++)
    {
        insert(expressionSplit[i]);
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: I removed the Node<T> root=null statement, as well as renamed the Node objects I pass as parameters, but it's still saying that root is null

Answer (score 0):

```
public Node<T> insert(Node<T> root, T data)
{

if(root==null)  // Problem  Use this.root
{
    root= new Node<T>(data); // Same here use this.root = new ....
    return root;
}
...
```